# Examples of "natural" combinatorial functions for which it has been proven that there is no closed-form expression

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form

I would be very interested for examples of "natural" combinatorial functions for which it has been rigorously proven that there is no closed-from expression. By "natural", I mean, not a function which grows too fast to be a closed-form function, like Busy Beaver, but rather, something like "the number of associative operations on an $n$-element set" or "the number of binary operations which are groups on an $n$-element set" or "the number of transitive binary relations on an $n$-element set". Has anyone, in some paper or book or text, given a rigorous definition of closed-form expression, and proven rigorously that there is no closed-form expression for a given "natural" "combinatorial" function?

Comment: The term *closed form* is context dependent. See for instance *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421120/what-does-the-formal-definition-of-closed-form-say-about-finite-sums-exactly/4421838#4421838)* for some info about this topic.

Comment: *[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236575/seeking-a-closed-expression-for-a-combinatorial-sum/3237461#3237461)* provides information that for instance *central trinomial coefficients* do not have a closed form, together with a nice theorem and a reference with a proof for it.

Answer (score 1):

The book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) is all about finding closed forms or proving their nonexistence for a large class of combinatorial sums.

Answer (score 0):

Take the definition in [Wikipedia: Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

It's not possible to prove that a closed-form solution doesn't exist, because you have to define which kind of expressions (functions, operations, symbols) you allow.

As mathematically well defined functions, you can get i. a. statements about the [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), the [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function) or some [Special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions).

There are only few problems for which it has been proven that they don't have solutions in the Elementary functions, the [Elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or the Liouvillian functions, e.g. Kepler's equation and Lambert W.
The proofs use Risch algorithm or Ritt-Risch structure theorem for Elementary functions.

See [Sequence for which no closed form can exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82732/sequence-for-which-no-closed-form-can-exist).